# Property 'value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable

Tags: powershell

I have written the below code to update the search vlaue to "X"

```
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 4;}    
$field1= $ie.document.getElementByID('C0_54')   
$field1.value="X"
```

But getting below error

Property 'value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:51 char:9
+ $field1. <<<< value="X"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (value:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

My Website Source Code:

```
<input class="textfield" type="text" name="0_54" title="Search Type" autocomplete="OFF" maxlength="3" value="*" style="vertical-align: top; width: 32px; padding-bottom: 1px; cursor: auto;" onhelp="hp('0_54')" onmouseover="updateHelpCursor('',this)" tabindex="4" id="C0_54" htmlpostflag="false" onfocus="FCHandler.onFocusVA(this,'',false)" onkeydown="FCHandler.onKeyDownTextField(this,'','3', event,false,'UTC')" onkeyup="FCHandler.onKeyUpTextField(this,'', event)" autosuggestenabled="1" mincharnumber="1" hotkey="0" isdropdown="1" onmousedown="FCHandler.onKeyDownTextField(this,'','3', event)" onblur="FCHandler.onExitVA(this,false,'',false)">
```

Comment: Typo: the correct method name is `getElementById` (seems like IE allows the misspelling though).

Comment: Yes its taking the name even with getElementByID